# How do I reference values in first Select from second Select in a Union?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm attempting to add a 'Total Sum' row of a calculated field to my query result for each 'Sales Rep' I have. I believe I should be using a union to add additional rows, but I would prefer not to have to re-calculate every field again.

This is expected outcome:

```
|SalesRep|Field1|Field2|CalculatedField|
------------------------------------------
|Bob     |value  |value  |12,000         |
|Bob     |value  |value  |3,000          |
|BobTotal|       |       |Sum(Calculated)|
|Tom     |value  |value  |400            |
|Tom     |value  |value  |800            |
|TomTotal|       |       |Sum(Calculated)|
```

So basically, I have this right now:

```
SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, (The Calculated Field)
FROM SalesRepTbl1
union
SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, (The Calculated Field)
FROM SalesRepTbl2
```

This get's me all the data I need, but not the sum of the calculated fields. What is my next step here?

Thank you!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which I would guess is SQL Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `grouping sets`:

```
select SalesRep, Field1, Field2, sum(calculated_field) as calculated_field
from ((SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, ? as calculated_field
       FROM SalesRepTbl1
      ) union all
      (SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, ? as calculated_field
       FROM SalesRepTbl2
      )
     ) s
group by grouping sets ( (SalesRep, Field1, Field2), (SalesRep) );
```

Note  I changed the subquery to use `union all` instead of `union`, because I assume that you do not want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: I had to read entirely about all the Group By Operators, but this is definitely what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, so I'm not sure if there's a way passed it(Maybe a CTE?), but I have to recalculate the field in the group by, because of the select statement getting processed after the group by. Best way to avoid calculating twice? It's pretty impactful.

Comment: @KirklandBrown373 . . . I don't understand your comment.  The calculated field would be calculated for every row in the two tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, (The Calculated Field)
FROM SalesRepTbl1
union
SELECT 'BobTotal' as Salesrep,  NULL as Field1, NULL as field2, sum(CalculatedField) as CalcualtedField
FROM SalesRepTbl1
union
SELECT SalesRep, Field1, Field2, (The Calculated Field)
FROM SalesRepTbl2
union
SELECT 'TomTotal' as Salesrep,  NULL as Field1, NULL as field2, sum(CalculatedField) as CalcualtedField
FROM SalesRepTbl2
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, not just the query

Comment: @dustytrash should I edit it now? It's more than 2 years old at this point and there's already a better, accepted answer.